# Debugging VisualForce Pages in Google chrome

Tags: visualforce, javascript, chrome

Sometimes I need to debug my visualforce pages for console application and this is what happens.

When I step through the javascript during debugging, For any of the calls encoutered for `sforce.console` API, it goes into this file named starting with "VM"..Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

As the file name always changes, I added the below expression in chrome debugger blackbox settings as shown below but still it steps through all the lines in this file.

[image]

Anybody had this issue and how did you solve this?